# CSS path implementing two conditions at same time

Tags: html, css, node.js

I am trying to find the css path and the situation is like this:

there are more than 20 child nodes, and i have to select every node which has fill not equal to none.

I know i can select a particular node using :nth-child(1) and select the node not having fill equal to none with :not([fill=none])

but how am i suppose to iterate through all the nodes which have fill not equal to none.

I have tried this:

div[nth-child(:not[fill=none]))

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
div:not([fill=none])
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Yup div:not([fill=none]) work individually , but it would return more than 1 element...I want to iterate through those elements.

Comment: If you want to work with each element individually, you should use JavaScript or jQuery. Here is example on jQuery https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/